# What does %s(%s) specifier do?

Tags: java, sql, string, specifier

I have a function that writes a sql query

I can't figure out what does the expression %s(%s) do in this function

```
public void createTable(String tabName) throws SQLException {
    String sql = "create table if not exists %s(%s)";
    sql = String.format(sql,
                        tabName,
                        String.format("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s",
                        "id int primary key auto_increment",
                        "surname varchar(50)",
                        "name varchar(50)",
                        "age int(3)",
                        "course int(1)",
                        "group varchar(50)",
                        "stateFunded int(1)"
                ));
    stat.execute(sql);
    System.out.println(sql);
}
```

I've tried to search, but there is no information about it in Google.

Comment: `%s` is a formatting placeholder for a string.

Comment: See the documentation of [`String.format(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)) which refers to the documentation about [format strings](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).

Comment: When in doubt, read the javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax

Comment: terrible code.... using two format strings as posted is good to confuse any developer (+ `%s`  used for literals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By itself `%s(%s)` is simply two string placeholder one after the other, with the second being surrounded by parentheses that have no syntactic meaning as far as `format` is concerned.

What this piece of code does is simply substituting the content of `tabName` for the first `%s` and the result of

```
String.format("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s",
                    "id int primary key auto_increment",
                    "surname varchar(50)",
                    "name varchar(50)",
                    "age int(3)",
                    "course int(1)",
                    "group varchar(50)",
                    "stateFunded int(1)")
```

for the second one, hence creating something along the lines of

```
create table if not exists tabName(
    id int primary key auto_increment,
    surname varchar(50),
    name varchar(50),
    age int(3),
    course int(1),
    group varchar(50),
    stateFunded int(1)
)
```

for whatever value `tabName` has.

Comment: Obligatory comment about using string formatting to build SQL: https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Of course, just writing all those fragments into a single string or using the good old `+` operator would not only make it obvious what’s going on, it would also keep all the compile-time constants constant, instead of performing unnecessary runtime operations.